# Show Admob interstitial ad when dialog dismissed after every 3rd time

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I'm new to interstitial ads. I show some info in dialog and was wondering if I could show an interstitial ad after 3rd time the dialog is dismissed in a single session.

Comment: Use sharedprefs to store the number of dialog dismisses.

Comment: I was thinking of the something similar...but I don't know what will be the most efficient way, sharedprefs or having a common public variable?

Comment: Shared prefs, reset on each startup in a custom `App` class.

Comment: If it is in a single session use a variable.